# Parcel per package maximum weight is 30 kg

Tags: php

Total max weight 50kg of three parts

Parcel per package maximum weight is 30 kg

Car Exhaust weight is: 20KG - Total Quantity 2 = 40KG

Car Alternator weight is: 10KG - Total Quantity 1 = 10KG

**So this requires two parcels**

- Parcel max weight 30kg Parcel 1 - Car Exhaust & Alternator (First parcel will take 1 Exhaust 20KG and 1 Alternator 10KG to make 30KG)
- Parcel max weight 30kg Parcel 2 - Car Exhaust (Second parcel will take 1 Exhaust of 20KG)

**Show like this:**

**Parcel No. ||  Part Name || Parts Quantity || Weight**

1 || Car Exhaust  || 1 || 20KG

1 || Alternator || 1 || 10KG

2 || Car Exhaust || 1 || 20KG

need to php script Show like this

(Code from comment/answer)...

```
$nums = array( 20, 20, 10 );

    sort($nums);
    $i=0;
    while($i<sizeof($nums)){
        $b=3;
        for ($k=1; $k < $b; $k++) { 
            dump($k);
        }
        die();
        $a = $nums[$i]+$nums[$i+1]+$nums[$i+2];
        if($a=30)
        {
            dump($a);
        }
        die();
        dump($i);
        if($i>=sizeof($nums)){

            break;
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $i=$i+1;
    }
```

Comment: need to php script Show like this.

Comment: Please add any code so far, we can help with specific problems with this code but I don't always feel like doing your work for you.

Comment: $nums = array( 20, 20, 10 );

  sort($nums);
  $i=0;
  while($i<sizeof($nums)){
   $b=3;
   for ($k=1; $k < $b; $k++) { 
    dump($k);
   }
   die();
   $a = $nums[$i]+$nums[$i+1]+$nums[$i+2];
   if($a=30)
   {
    dump($a);
   }
   die();
   dump($i);
   if($i>=sizeof($nums)){

    break;
   }
   echo "<br>";
   $i=$i+1;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you'd have to try it to make sure, but there are comments in the code which should show you how it works...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$parts = [ [ 'desc' => 'Exhaust', 'weight' =>20],
    ['desc' => 'Car Exhaust2', 'weight' => 20],
    ['desc' => 'Alternator', 'weight' => 10]
];
$maxWeight = 30;
$parcels = [];

// Create first parcel
$parcels[] = ['weight' => 0, 'items' => []];
foreach ( $parts as $item ) {
    $added = false;
    // Look through all existing parcels
    foreach ( $parcels as &$parcel ) {
        // If there is enough space for this item - add to parcel
        if ( $parcel['weight'] + $item['weight'] <= $maxWeight ) {
            $parcel['weight'] += $item['weight'];
            $parcel['items'][] = $item;
            $added = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If there wasn't enough space in existing parcels, create a new one
    if ( $added == false )  {
        $parcels[] = ['weight' => $item['weight'], 'items' => [$item]];
    }
}

print_r($parcels);
```

I've expanded the item array to have a description as well as the weight, then each parcel has a total weight of the items in it and a list of the items.

The max weight is a variable and so can be change easily.

You will need to try it with different items, but it's fairly simple at what it does.